# Fetch Previous hour file-GetFTP-NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to fetch files from Previous hour using GetFTP Processor.
I tried to find regular expression which matches the filename with previous hour but I did not find any. Could you please help me in fetching the files with file filter regular expression in below format and the folder contains current hour and previous hour files.

```
Current_time=10:00
file to fetch= file-09.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get file of previous hour by using FetchFTP processor. I used the following Expression Language in the "Remote File" property of FetchFTP.

```
file-${now():format('HH'):toNumber():minus(1):toString():padLeft(2, '0')}.log
```

Comment: I have applied the same for GetSFTP processor but it is throwing me an error like " Invalid because not a valid java regular expression"

Comment: GetFTP or GetSFTP's file selection property (File Filter Regex) does not support NiFi Expression language. For that reason, I used FetchFTP processor to set the required file name. FetchFTP's file selection property (Remote File) supports Expression language.